# How to replace permissions with Setacl

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I currently have:
(SET _KEY=C:\Windows\SystemApps)
%~d0\Batch\SetACL.exe -on "%_KEY%" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:%username%;p:full
%~d0\Batch\SetACL.exe -on "%_KEY%" -ot file -actn ace -actn -clr "n:SYSTEM;p:full
%~d0\Batch\SetACL.exe -on "%_KEY%" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:SYSTEM;p:full

It does nothing for this file:
C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\core\js\appLaunchers\WindowsCoreLocalAccountCreator.js

[Current Permissions][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6rhw.jpg

I need to change the permissions so i can delete the file. I'm running in Windows 10. My user has administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question.
This allows me to delete the file:

```
Set "Key=C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\core\js\appLaunchers\WindowsCoreLocalAccountCreator.js"
%~d0\Batch\setacl -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn setowner -ownr "n:%username%"
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn trustee -trst n1:System;ta:remtrst;w:dacl
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn trustee -trst n1:"ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES";ta:remtrst;w:dacl
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn trustee -trst n1:"ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES";ta:remtrst;w:dacl
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn trustee -trst n1:Administrators;ta:remtrst;w:dacl
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%Key%" -ot file -actn trustee -trst n1:Users;ta:remtrst;w:dacl
%~d0\Batch\SetACL -on "%KEY%" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:%username%;p:full"
```